# What is there to do at level 70 without buying The Lich King?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If I don't decide for a while to put down the money for The Lich King (everyone has Burring Crusade now), and I level a character to level 70, what can I expect to be doing in the game without the other expansions, not including leveling another character?

I was thinking PvP, but that would put me in the lowest level of my bracket at 70.

Would raids be worth the gear I get? I'm worried that after level 70 they won't be good enough to use, and I'll have wasted my time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options open to you.

1) Replay old content, daily quests etc and get your faction rep up, 100% complete all quests in all zones.

2) PvP to get your rank up, earn armour etc, you can also use your resources to create a new lvl 19,29,39 character to PvP.

3) Join a guild dedicated to lvl70 raiding and do the old dungeons and heroics.

4) Create new characters with new classes, play as the other faction

Honestly though WOTLK is out and finished now, Cataclysm is already way on its way I would just bite the bullet and get WOTLK its really cheap now ive seen it for like £4 in places. If you dont get WOTLK / Cataclysm soon by the time the next expansion is out you are going to get so far behind that when everyone is doing the next expansion you are still doing the old tired content.

Comment: The random dungeon queue linked to other servers is great, I use that all the time when I play with my 70.

Answer (score 1):

You can join a level 70 guild and depending on what you like more you can go pvp or raiding.

Comment: Pretty much this. It's either "find other people who are level 70 and act like it's the level cap", or just keep leveling.

Comment: there are still some guilds with people that don't buy more than TBC even kick you if u do so i guess that would be the best option :D

Comment: Hmmm there are some guilds that only do the vanilla wow raids aswell. What most people don't know is that you can level a char to 60 and then stop it from leveling any further.

Comment: yep for 10g costs or something mostly made for the twinks however if u don't want to go on after level 60 or 70 u can also use it :D